# Azure Ad b2c : change current email pattern validation on signup

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an application running on azure ad b2c.

I have requirement to restrict email to only one domain. for this I have to change pattern in Email claim.

What I have tried it is I changed it in basepolicy and uploaded it. I got some new issues while signin.because that base policy was not matching the requirement of current signup-signin policy. I have downloaded it from custom policy starter packs.

Is there any another way to do this? OR any way to change the existing signup-signin policy.

Comment: Is the existing sign-up or sign-in policy a built-in one rather than a custom one?

Comment: Yes Chris, this is the built in one. I have changed the pattern in email claim. And uploaded it along with base and base extensions.

Answer (score 2):

A built-in policy can't be affected by a custom policy since each is derived from different policy structures. The policy structure for a built-in policy is managed by Microsoft. The policy structure for a custom policy is managed by you.

You can't change the regular expression of the **email** claim for a built-in policy so you'll have to create the custom policy and replace the built-in one with this custom one.